# How to Limit the color channels in a PDF file

Tags: wpf, pdf, printing, acrobat, cmyk

I have created a WPF system, it uses CMYK colors and works only with two channels: black and magenta. The problem I have is when I print the output to Adobe Acrobat Printer, the resulting PDF file has outputs in all four channels, For example:

When I have a shade of gray, the resulting output uses a mixture of all four channels to reproduce to gray, and this is not what I want: My output will go to a press system with only magenta and black channels.

It seems that the pdf printer does not respect CMYK values in the printed document and uses their RGB values to guess a good CMYK equivalent.

How can I force PDF to respect my color values?

Comment: Does your PDF file do the right thing? In other words, you are certain that the PDF file you generate contains only black and magenta?

Comment: No. The problem is exactly that it contains all channels.

Comment: OK, so it's not the interpretation of the PDF file but the generation that is incorrect. Can you specify output settings while printing to the Acrobat Printer? What you see happening is probably an icc based color conversion (which typically generates unwanted channels) - are there options you can control while printing that would switch off color management for the Acrobat Printer?

Comment: in "Adobe color settings" I've set "Setting File"-> None
And in "Color Management Policies" Selected "Leave Color Unchanged"
Well, I've actually tried many more different settings, none seem to work.

Comment: Is there a way to export these settings or show what exactly you are using? Is there a Rendering Intent setting you can select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use websupergoos [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) when it comes to CMYK-pdf-creation. Costs a few bucks thou...

Answer (score 1):

My guess the problem is with the Windows printing subsystem that performs some CMYK->RGB->CMYK conversion along the way. The PDF printers are not really designed to create such specialized PDF files.
My recommendation is to use a 3rd party PDF library that can generate PDF files and gives you full control over the colors in the PDF file.

Comment: This is indeed the root of the problem.
And do you know about a good 3rd party tool or library?

Comment: I can recommend the product developed by the company I work for, XFINIUM.PDF: www.xfiniumpdf.com

Comment: Thanx, I gave the product a rapid test. The Cmyk is output perfectly well. BTW, I need support for complex scripts (Bidirectional text) and non-ASCII chars . The rapid test failed, is this supported by your product?

Comment: Please send an email to support and they will help you.